# Best approach & tool to do performance testing in order to compare old system and New system

Tags: performance-testing

I got a requirement to do performance testing comparing the old system with the new system.
Basically migrated from the cloud to AWS so the requirement is to check the performance for all the critical functionality.
Can anyone please suggest me the best tool to do this and what sort of approach I can follow?
Also please suggest to me how I can record and show the evidence? any tools?

Comment: What you did so far? Is there any limitation of mainstream load testing tools, such as JMeter, Locust, Gatling, etc, in your context? What do you mean by "comparing" and "check the performance" in terms of metrics?

Comment: Yes, in terms of Metrics.

Comment: My question was "in terms of metrics, what information do you want to extract in order to compare the two systems?"

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to implement a [load test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing)

1. Implement the scenario(s) of your application usage by real users (or other systems) using a [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use/)
2. Execute the test against the "old" system and collect relevant [metrics](https://www.monitis.com/blog/most-important-metrics-for-your-website-performance/), the key ones are:

- average response time (as well as [percentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile))
- throughput (number or requests per second)
- number of errors

3. Execute the same test against the "new" system and collect the same metrics
4. Compare "old" and "new" ones, the "new" ones should be not worse than the "old"

Comment: How many users I had to test for comparing both system performance? Do we have any standard values defined? or its based on server capacity? How do I define that? Please guide me. Thanks for your valuable answer.